# Inject components dynamically into another component at a specified location

Tags: typescript, angular

In our application we have a `DashboardComponent` that has a number of tiles based on configuration / permissions / etc. These "tiles" can be in any order based on user preferences.

The task seems simple:

> Create a placeholder in the template, then select the placeholder and inject/instantiate the components into the view based on the requirements

For example:

```
@Component({
  ...,
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div #placeholder></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class DashboardComponent{

  constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService){}

  ngOnInit(): void{
    // Get all tiles that should be displayed for this user in order
    const tiles = this.dashboardService.getTiles();
    // Inject / instantiate the components into the DasboardComponent at #placeholder
  }
}
```

Note: A "Tile" is a first class `@Component`. For example I have a `ProfileTileComponent` and an `ArticlesTileComponent`.

I can create a `ComponentFactory / ComponentResolver` but how do I tell it where to place it in the DOM?

I tried grabbing a reference to `#placeholder` using `@ViewChild`, but that doesn't appear to give me the correct object back.

`@Query` appears to be deprecated, so I didn't look further into that.

`Renderer` doesn't appear to instantiate components

I'm quite sure this is possible in Angular 2 but is just not documented.

This is an Angular2.0.0-rc.4 application.